# Capital letters

Tags: capitalization

I was wondering if I should capitalize the words 'case' and 'letter' when I write this question:

Define the following terms:

Upper case letter:

Lower case letter:

OR

Upper Case Letter:

Lower Case Letter:

Thank you.

Comment: Just send to ELL - no need to vote down.  try the great ELL site, Hellena!

Comment: I'd say ELL too, though I'd also say the question should indicate whether they care about use in titles, in sentences, or both.

Answer (score 2):

You would always use "Upper case letter" or "Lower case letter"

Unless it is a name or unique thing, like a book title (Lord of the Rings, Harry Potter, ect) or a place (Stonehenge, Statue of Liberty, ect), You only every capitalize the first letter of every sentence.

Also, you may be interested in posting to English Language Learners, out sister site.